# Cakephp: How to get table data without creating Models/Controllers?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My doubt is, I had few tables named client1,client2,client3 etc., I need to get the data of each client in single controller without creating any model/controller for each table. Can any one explain how to get those values.

Comment: A model represents data, and a controller (usually) fetches that data. Now, why are you *not* wanting to use these? As otherwise, there’s no point in using an MVC framework like CakePHP if you’re not wanting to adhere to MVC principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dynamic models

app/client_model.php

```
<?php
    class ClientModel extends Model {
        var $name = 'Client';
        var $alias = 'Client';

        function __construct($table) {
            $this->useTable = $table;
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
?>
```

And Use like this for client1 table

```
    App::import('model','Client');
    $client = new ClientModel('client1');
    $client->find('all');
```

Comment: I ended up using this - I have an EmailForms controller/model and I needed and EmailFormSubmissions controller/model, and for various terrible reasons I could not write them as two separate model/controllers - I had only one model/controller available to do double duty. So I insantiate a new EmailForm like this:    $emailFormSubmission = new EmailForm('email_form_submissions');

Answer (score -1):

You   Can do it by firing normal mysql queries selecting table and fetching values
      in controller as we do in core php.

Comment: Yeah, I had done in that way. But feeling like, what's need of doing it in a framework?

Comment: Yes I know but i think this is the solution matching to your requirement.